# How to check if file is in locked mode?

Tags: java

Can someone help me to check file is already in locked mode?

My program is unable to read the file because it is in locked mode, Then I re-create file again and my programme read file with no issue.

so is there any way to check file is already in locked mode?

Comment: [Research a little bit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/package-summary.html)

Comment: Try to write to file.It will be locked if you fail to write or try canWrite() java method from Java File API. Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite()

Answer (score 1):

The "research" suggested above gives no hint as to how to see if a file is locked. Method canWrite will return true even if the file is locked. What canWrite can do is to check to see if the directory is writable. If the directory and file are both writable but a write to the file fails, then the file is most likely locked.

My test code:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    File f = new File("junk.txt");
    File dir = f.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile();
    System.out.println("can write dir " + dir.getName()+": "+dir.canWrite());
    System.out.println("can write " + f.getName()+": "+f.canWrite());
    try (Writer w = new FileWriter(f)) {
        w.append("world\n");
        System.out.println("write succeeded");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("write failed");
    }
}
```

In a test, I locked junk.txt by opening it in excel. When the file is locked, the output is

```
    can write dir tools: true
    can write junk.txt: true
    write failed
```

When the file is not locked the write succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write to the file.It will be locked if you fail to write

or

try canWrite() java method from Java File API.

Refer: docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite()

Comment: How can you differentiate between missing permissions and a locked file ?

Comment: @Marged :The original question poster has no permission issues.As, he is able to read the second time.It throws SecurityException, if a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkWrite() method denies write access to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Write to the file, if it fails, that means your file is locked.

```
File f = new File("suspiciousLockedFile.txt");
System.out.println(f.canWrite());
```

Comment: @Pramod What's the solution you need ? Your question was how to check a file whether its locked.

Comment: My file has only read permission but somehow it goes into a locked mode so how would I know it is in locked mode.

Comment: Test your file whether it can be written using `canWrite()` , if it success (a locked file cannot be written) , continue with your program, else, generate some error message to users.

Comment: Or you can set `fileWritable()` to `true` if you want your file to be writable , or set `fileReadOnly()` to restrict read only permission